# How to run Django 1.6 LiveServerTestCase without HTTPS?

Tags: python, django, http, testing, https

I have a Django 1.6 project in which I'm trying to run LiveServerTestCase. However, I don't need HTTPS for my test case, so I'd like to disable it. Is there a way to do this?

I run:

```
$ website/manage.py test website/tests.py:MySeleniumTests
```

and Firefox opens pointed at:

```
https://localhost:8081/
```

I am able to run a secure server on port 8081 with:

```
$ website/manage.py runserver_plus --cert cert 0.0.0.0:8081

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'south',
'website.nucleus',
'website.blog',
'django_extensions',
'debug_toolbar',
'django_nose',
'django_coverage',
'tinymce',
'django_ztask',
'timezones',
'tracking',
'gunicorn',
'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
'report_builder',
'bootstrapform',
'bootstrap3',
```

)

Comment: Do you mean that the browser opens up web pages under `https://...` urls? Could you show how do you run the tests? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the question with details.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you also show `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings?

Comment: I started posting MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES when I realized that we had an SSL REDIRECT middleware installed. I commented that out, and voila, the live server and my selenium tests started working! If you want to write up: look for SSL REDIRECT middleware as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it answered. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked since according to the source code, by default it is `http` protocol used. Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Django uses `http://` protocol for live server tests, quote from the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4b25ebf112d8bf4fcee6ee8339913bffdc81035d/django/test/testcases.py#L1162-L1165):

```
class LiveServerTestCase(TransactionTestCase):
    static_handler = _StaticFilesHandler

    @property
    def live_server_url(self):
        return 'http://%s:%s' % (
            self.server_thread.host, self.server_thread.port)
```

Since, you see `https://` protocol used in tests, something is redirecting your requests to `https`. Check your [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES) setting.

For example, [`django-ssl-redirect`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ssl-redirect) middleware could be the culprit.